# Save "DataFrame.style" table in Jupyter as png?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

With this code I am able to display a table in JuPyter. Now here is the problem: Usually i use matplotlib to plot and and save the plot as a PNG:

> plot.savefig("foo.png", bbox_inches='tight')

But in this case below, there is no matplotlib involved. So how can i save my table as a PNG here?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(24)
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': np.linspace(1, 10, 10)})
df = pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10, 4), columns=list('BCDE'))],
               axis=1)
df.iloc[0, 2] = np.nan
df.style
```

Comment: I literally just screen-captured it.

Comment: can you maybe help?